# Getting an Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-9esxx.gcp.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, server

I do not really know why I keep getting this error "Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-9esxx.gcp.mongodb.net" when I try to run my node app. Is it from the server or because of a poor internet?
This is the database.js file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            // to avoid warnings in the console
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        });

        console.log(`mongoDB connected ${conn.connection.host}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // stop the process
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: Add the full error message verbatim to the question.

Comment: It's most likely an issue with your MongoDB connection string, can you confirm that the `process.env.MONGO_URI`environment variable is a valid MongoDB connection string? Perhaps, add a console.log withing your code to see what value is used at runtime.

Comment: This was the full error message
Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-9esxx.gcp.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-9esxx.gcp.mongodb.net'
}

Comment: Now, it is able to connect to the connection.host as per my database.js file but I can't access the page. I keeps consoling this "GET / - - ms - -" in the terminal and the browser page keeps loading

Comment: So when I npm run dev, this happens
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
server running in development on port 3000 //console.log(`server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`)
mongoDB connected cluster0-shard-00-00-9esxx.gcp.mongodb.net //console.log(`mongoDB connected ${conn.connection.host}`);
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
until I terminate the session